# wordpress nav pages not showing content

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a beginner in wordpress , when I click a navbar link it open but display the same content of the home page

these are screenshots

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjjUt5PVIDDuklejTWlJOH1YloK2?e=vUEU5Q

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjjUt5PVIDDukljkjqXd-g9gRAdg?e=IezYxx

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjjUt5PVIDDuklbGIDxIAtVrgQME?e=xzIKD2

this is my about.php code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        about
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check menu settings (go to appearence->menus) and select the menu assigned ( maybe as primary menu in Display location) and check whether you have # instead of the actual link.

Answer (score 0):

On the editing page of your "About us", click on the "Document tab" and check the permalink if it's linking to the actual menu items, if not, edit them and label them as such. You can also create all your pages, delete your current menu items and recreate the menus all over, the link will be automatically applied.